# tcp syn retransmission after recieving RST?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, wireshark

I am using a simulator. in this simulator when a client sends a tcp syn request to a server and server responds it with RST packet (when the requesting port is close) the same client sends tcp syn retransmission to the same server (and the same port) for four times. i want to know real networks do the same? i mean in real networks if a client sends a tcp syn to a server and recieve RST , do that client sends tcp syn retransmission to that server for four times?

Comment: Or, it could be a server trying to contact a client, and the client is sending the RST. TCP has no concept of clients or servers, that is is an application concept. TCP creates connections between two peer TCPs. We have servers that initiate contact with the clients to gather information and make updates.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the client implementation. If you program a client to respond to a server's RST with a SYN 4 times, then that's what it will do. It might be that the server is sending an RST because it's detecting a [SYN flood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood) (if you keep on sending SYNs unsuccessfully, eventually heuristics will class it as such).

You may want to play with [Scapy](https://scapy.net/) so you can easily write the client for these kinds of questions.